# Как управлять длиной ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb?

Tags: html, css, webkit, scrollbar

Webkit поддерживает стилизацию скролл-бара средствами CSS3. И всё бы хорошо, но почему-то не получается у меня изменять длину бегунка. И width пробовал, и height - ничего не помогает. Есть у кого идеи?

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #8c1b21;
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #B79889;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #8c1b21;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: С этой задачей справится отличный плагин https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar

Comment: Эм.. Вероятно никак. Она же не с потолка берётся.

Answer (score 1):

Если стоит задача сделать бегунок уже скроллбара - можно задать ему границу в цвет полосы прокрутки.
 А длина бегунка рассчитывается браузером исходя из количества контента и размеров самого блока.

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#child {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #8c1b21;
}

#parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #B79889;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


#parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #B79889;
  background-color: #8c1b21;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```